# Should Marshal.FreeHGlobal be Called or LocalFree?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanagedresources

Seen a piece of code which I'm not sure whether I need to release memory. If I have this block below:

```
IntPtr buf = new IntPtr(logRecord.ToInt32() + logTotalCount * 
                  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeUnmanagedStruct)));
```

Do I need to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf)`?

From my limited understanding (and from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525932/should-marshal-freehglobal-be-placed-in-a-finally-block-to-ensure-resources-are)), I don't think we should call `FreeHGlobal` as we are not calling `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. However, I have also read from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949084/how-marshal-freehglobal-works) that `LocalFree` may need to be called?

Any advise what is the correct way to free this memory (if I need to do anything at all)?

UPDATE: Just in case anyone is interested in a IDISPOSABLE wrapper class, there is a great article [here](http://goldfishforthought.blogspot.ae/2007/09/leaking-memory-with-marshalallochglobal.html).

Comment: There's no memory allocation, so there's nothing to free. It's not clear to me what you think your line of code does. Can you explain what it does?

Comment: Aha OK I thought that might be the case. I've received this code from someone else, so trying to work out what buf is being used for as it is passed into a parameter to a 3rd party C++ API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unsure what one of the base class library actually does, you can always look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,d99bf6ad49979009):

```
public struct IntPtr : ISerializable
{
    [SecurityCritical]
    unsafe private void* m_value; // The compiler treats void* closest to uint 
                                  // hence explicit casts are required to preserve int
                                  // behavior

    public unsafe IntPtr(int value)
    {
        #if WIN32
            m_value = (void *)value;
        #else
            m_value = (void *)(long)value;
        #endif
    }
}
```

As you can see, this isn't actually allocating any unmanaged memory, but rather simply assigning the `int` to a private `void*`.

Comment: Perfect answer :) Clear. Thank you very much. I'll set this as the solution after SO lets me to (in 5 mins) :)